# Sql request to get an ordered menu

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

Right now, I build my menu doing many request and loop with symfony.
I would like to be able to retrieve the same thing in a single sql request

```
MenuItem (Id,parent_id,level,weight)
```

parent_id is a reference to an other MenuItem

If I have these records

> 1,null,1,50
>
> 2,null,1,20
>
> 3,1,2,100
>
> 4,1,2,0
>
> 5,2,2,40
>
> 6,5,3,900
>
> 7,5,3,500

I want the results to be

> 2
>
> > 5
> >
> > > 7
> > >
> > > 6
>
> 1
>
> > 4
> >
> > 3

The weigtht attribute is used to order the menu items inside their own level.

That means id 2 come before id 1 because weight 20 < weight 50 but id 2 still comes before id 4 because level 1 < level 2

I'm not even sure this is possible.

EDIT: Right now, I have to do something very ugly

```
$menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
$menu->setLabel("Menu");

$item_repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MenuItem::class);
//profondeur max defini à 5
//On récupère les items du niveau 1 trié par poids (profondeur)
$items_lv1 = $item_repository->findBy(array('menu' => $id_main_menu,'active' => 1, 'niveau' => 1),array('poids' => 'ASC'));
//On récupère les items du niveau 2 trié par parent et poids (profondeur)
$items_lv2 = $item_repository->findBy(array('menu' => $id_main_menu,'active' => 1,'niveau' => 2),array('parent' => 'ASC','poids' => 'ASC'));
$items_lv3 = $item_repository->findBy(array('menu' => $id_main_menu,'active' => 1,'niveau' => 3),array('parent' => 'ASC','poids' => 'ASC'));
$items_lv4 = $item_repository->findBy(array('menu' => $id_main_menu,'active' => 1,'niveau' => 4),array('parent' => 'ASC','poids' => 'ASC'));
$items_lv5 = $item_repository->findBy(array('menu' => $id_main_menu,'active' => 1,'niveau' => 5),array('parent' => 'ASC','poids' => 'ASC'));

$cptLv1 = 1;
foreach ($items_lv1 as $item_lv1){
    $lv1 = $menu->addChild($cptLv1,
        ['uri' => $item_lv1->getUrl(),'label' => $item_lv1->getLabel(),
            'attributes' => array('title' => $item_lv1->getTitle(),
            'id_css' => $item_lv1->getIdCss(), 'class_css' => $item_lv1->getClassCss(), 'target' => $item_lv1->getTarget())]);
    $cptLv2 = 1;
    foreach ($items_lv2 as $item_lv2){
        if($item_lv2->getParent()->getUrl() == $item_lv1->getUrl()){
            $lv2 = $lv1->addChild($cptLv1.$cptLv2,
                ['uri' => $item_lv2->getUrl(),'label' => $item_lv2->getLabel(),
                    'attributes' => array('title' => $item_lv2->getTitle(),
                    'id_css' => $item_lv2->getIdCss(), 'class_css' => $item_lv2->getClassCss(), 'target' => $item_lv2->getTarget())]);
            $cptLv3 = 1;
            foreach ($items_lv3 as $item_lv3){
                if($item_lv3->getParent()->getUrl() == $item_lv2->getUrl()) {
                    $lv3 = $lv2->addChild($cptLv1.$cptLv2.$cptLv3,
                        ['uri' => $item_lv3->getUrl(), 'label' => $item_lv3->getLabel(),
                            'attributes' => array('title' => $item_lv3->getTitle(),
                            'id_css' => $item_lv3->getIdCss(), 'class_css' => $item_lv3->getClassCss(), 'target' => $item_lv3->getTarget())]);
                    $cptLv4 = 1;
                    foreach ($items_lv4 as $item_lv4){
                        if($item_lv4->getParent()->getUrl() == $item_lv3->getUrl()) {
                            $lv4 = $lv3->addChild($cptLv1.$cptLv2.$cptLv3.$cptLv4,
                                ['uri' => $item_lv4->getUrl(), 'label' => $item_lv4->getLabel(),
                                    'attributes' => array('title' => $item_lv4->getTitle(),
                                    'id_css' => $item_lv4->getIdCss(), 'class_css' => $item_lv4->getClassCss(), 'target' => $item_lv4->getTarget())]);
                            $cptLv5 = 1;
                            foreach ($items_lv5 as $item_lv5){
                                if($item_lv5->getParent()->getUrl() == $item_lv4->getUrl()) {
                                    $lv4->addChild($cptLv1.$cptLv2.$cptLv3.$cptLv4.$cptLv5,
                                        ['uri' => $item_lv5->getUrl(), 'label' => $item_lv5->getLabel(),
                                            'attributes' => array('title' => $item_lv5->getTitle(),
                                            'id_css' => $item_lv5->getIdCss(), 'class_css' => $item_lv5->getClassCss(), 'target' => $item_lv5->getTarget())]);
                                }
                                $cptLv4 += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        $cptLv4 += 1;
                    }
                }
                $cptLv3 += 1;
            }
        }
        $cptLv2 +=1;
    }
    $cptLv1+=1;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,parent_id INT NULL
,level INT NOT NULL
,weight INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,null,1,50),
(2,null,1,20),
(3,1,2,100),
(4,1,2,0);

SELECT *,COALESCE(y.level,x.level) my_level,COALESCE(y.weight,x.weight) my_weight FROM my_table x LEFT JOIN my_table y ON y.id = x.parent_id;
+----+-----------+-------+--------+------+-----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
| id | parent_id | level | weight | id   | parent_id | level | weight | my_level | my_weight |
+----+-----------+-------+--------+------+-----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |      NULL |     1 |     50 | NULL |      NULL |  NULL |   NULL |        1 |        50 |
|  2 |      NULL |     1 |     20 | NULL |      NULL |  NULL |   NULL |        1 |        20 |
|  3 |         1 |     2 |    100 |    1 |      NULL |     1 |     50 |        1 |        50 |
|  4 |         1 |     2 |      0 |    1 |      NULL |     1 |     50 |        1 |        50 |
+----+-----------+-------+--------+------+-----------+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Extract from that whatever you like.

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for except that with this request the weight seems to be DESC instead of ASC. Thanks a lot anyway I didn't knew about this COALESCE

Comment: There's no ORDER BY clause in my query. So despite appearances, the rows are simply unordered.

Comment: That means it's not possible to order them the way I need in the request ? I tried to order by x.weight but this is not working^^

Comment: If you were to order by x.weight, then there would be no point joining the table to itself! Your data set is not sufficiently representative to confirm the order you desire, and it's always nice to use a different scale of numbers for different things, so levels could be level 1000 and level 2000, to distinguish them from ids.

Comment: Well with words it's quite simple: I want to order the dataset by weight asc among all the item with the same parent and level. Lv1 is ordered by weight ASC -- LvN is ordered by parent id and weight ASC

Comment: Asi i say, the data set it insufficiently representative. All level n data share the same parents.

Comment: I made a mistake in the previous example :( I edited and added more data

Comment: See what I did above. Do that.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to use level and weight ... just use the weight ("order" would be better).

do not worry if id 2 is before or after id 4, because id4 is in id2 (parent level).

an element with parent_id = null is a id with level 0.

think like this :

```
 select Id,parent_id,level  ,weight from mytable order by level,weight
```

Here is a piece of code that allows you, after your select, to have a recursive table that you can browse to display the menus.
It takes into account that an element can be related to "null" (root), and that there can be non-consecutive "weights" ...

**the $ result variable is constructed as if you had made a select with a sort on level + weight**

```
<style>

 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
 }


 li {
  margin-left:2em;
  border-left:solid 2px green;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:1em;
 }


</style>

<?php 

 /* 
  * warn ! this array looks like a result after a select, ordered by level+weight 
  */
 $result=array(
   array(   'id'=>2,   'parent_id'=>null,   'level'=>1,   'weight'=>20  ),
   array(   'id'=>1,   'parent_id'=>null,   'level'=>1,   'weight'=>50  ),

   array(   'id'=>4,   'parent_id'=>1,    'level'=>2,   'weight'=>0   ),
   array(   'id'=>3,   'parent_id'=>1,     'level'=>2,   'weight'=>100  ),

   array(   'id'=>5,   'parent_id'=>2,    'level'=>2,   'weight'=>40   ),

   array(   'id'=>7,   'parent_id'=>5,    'level'=>3,   'weight'=>500   ),
   array(   'id'=>6,   'parent_id'=>5,    'level'=>3,   'weight'=>900   )
);


 // store recursive array of menus
 $menus=array();

 // store link of an id in the recursive array of menus 
 $keysIds=array();

 // start with a empty menu
 $menus[0]=array('element'=>'ROOT','subMenus'=>array());
 $keysIds[0]=&$menus[0];

 // build a menus array  
 foreach ($result as $element) {

    $idParent=$element['parent_id'];
    $id=$element['id'];

    // check for idParent=0 !!     
    if ($idParent==null) {
        $idParent=0;
    }

    // check if parent exists
    // don't forget, result is sorted by level+weight,
    // so the idParent is always in array
    if (!isset($keysIds[$idParent])) {
        echo "<H2>PARENT = $idParent , not exists while INSERTING Id {$id} </H2>";
        continue;
    }

    // JSON index sorting prevention    
    $max=sizeof($keysIds[$idParent]['subMenus']);
    // create a entry
    $keysIds[$idParent]['subMenus'][$max]=array('element'=>$element,'subMenus'=>array());
    // for next entries, keep this id accessible quickly..it can be a parent.
    $keysIds[$id]=&$keysIds[$idParent]['subMenus'][$max]; 

 }


 // show the HTML LISTE   
 htmlMenus($menus,0);


 // Recursive iteration on $menus   
 function htmlMenus($root,$listeLevel) {
     echo str_repeat(" ", $listeLevel*2); // beautifull source...
     echo "<ul>\n";    
     foreach ($root as $datas) {
         echo str_repeat(" ", $listeLevel*2+2);
         echo "<li>\n ";
         if ($datas['element']!='ROOT') {
             echo str_repeat(" ", $listeLevel*2+2);
             echo "ID : {$datas['element']['id']} weight:{$datas['element']['weight']}\n";
         }
         htmlMenus($datas['subMenus'],$listeLevel+1);
         echo str_repeat(" ", $listeLevel*2+2);
         echo '</li>';             
     }
     echo str_repeat(" ", $listeLevel*2);
     echo "</ul>\n"; 
 }
```

Comment: This can't work I can't predict in advance what will be the parent_id. May be in production many item will be deleted and I will have a first level item with an id 1000 while I will have a second level item with an id 5.

Comment: Yep , i just understood the way you thinks, 'select' must be sorted by level and weight, it will works.

Comment: Code and comments updated, select order y level,weight